# Deleting with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two CSV email lists of contacts with email addresses. One list is the "subscribe list" and the second list is the "unsubscribe" list (which contains the emails that need to be deleted from the "subscribe" list).  I am new to MySQL and would like to know how I can delete the "unsubscribe" emails from the "subscribe" list.
Your help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: do you have two mysql tables, or just two CSV files?

Comment: and i also made two mysql tables

Comment: Please give us some details about your DB design.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I have two tables, mailing(full list) with 6 columns (fname, lname, email, phone, city, country). And the other table, unsubscribe with just one column (noemail).

Comment: Please update your question with a more accurate description. Thanks!

Comment: ok, let's say i have two tables subscribe and unsubscribe. Both have only one column (email) the first one and (noemail) the second one. I would like to delete all the unsubscribe from subscribe. I tried the code below but it is giving me an error (Eror in processing request, error code 500, Error text: internal server error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have imported your two CSV files already, you could use a simple DELETE query with IN clause:

```
DELETE FROM subscribe
WHERE subscribe.email IN (SELECT email FROM unsubscribe)
```